# Missing required param "data"

Tags: vuejs3

When I pass the params in a new tab and try to access it , I get the error Missing required param "data".

Here the code.

```
{
    path: '/bill/:data',
    name: 'bill',
    component: Bill,
    meta:{public: true}
}
```

here am opening the new tab

```
const routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'bill', query: {data: "TESTDATA123"}});
  window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

and here is where am retrieving the data

```
console.log('params '+ this.$route.params['data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to save the data in local storage then accessed it from the other side

```
        localStorage['params'] = JSON.stringify({
          businessID: this.businessID
        })
        const routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'trade'});
        window.open(routeData.href, '_blank');
```

The from the other side I retrieved it like this.

```
let params = {}
    try {
      params = JSON.parse(localStorage['params'])
      console.log('####'+ params.receiptNo)
      this.getReceipt(params.receiptNo);
    } catch (error) {
      // ignore
    }
```